# javascript cleartimeout() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My main question is: Does clearTimeout() stop the timer AND not execute the function within the timer?  OR does it just clear the timeout and immediately execute the function?

Here's my example

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        var thisError = $(this).parent().siblings('.error');
        var thisTimeout;
        if(thisClass[1] == "letters"){
            if(thisValue.length <= 1){
                thisTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    thisError.html("You must have at least 2 characters");  
                    thisError.show();
                }, 800);
            } else {
                clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
                thisError.hide();
                thisError.html(""); 
            }
        }

    });
```

This is part of a code checks to see if an input box has at least 2 characters in it.
currently, This code executes the timeout well after 800 miliseconds if it has 2 or less characters.  When the input box has more than 2 characters, if I'm typing fast enough, the error box still shows up when I finish typing.  I can clear the error by typing one more character, but if I were to type my name quickly, The error shows up when I'm done typing.

I also have this piece of code:

```
$('input').keydown(function(){
        clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
        thisError.hide();
    });
```

Hoping that it would clear the error if I kept typing
Thoughts?

Comment: `thisTimeout` should be declared out of `if`, so its visible at `else` part too

Comment: I did try this before, though I got the same results - I've updated my code above to show the previous code - and I will keep it this way

Comment: @ntgCleaner Javascript engines will move `thisTimeout` outside the `if` function anyway, which is why it still worked.

Comment: @RodrigoAssis JavaScript does not have block scope, only new functions create new scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first question you asked:

> Does clearTimeout() stop the timer AND not execute the function within
>   the timer? OR does it just clear the timeout and immediately execute
>   the function?

The answer is the first option – `clearTimeout` stops the timer and does not execute the timer callback.

The problem in your code question is because `thisTimeout` is declared inside the `keyup` function. The `keydown` function doesn't have a reference to `thisTimeout`.

You should move it to a shared scope instead:

```
var thisTimeout;

$('input').keyup(function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    var thisValue = $(this).val();
    var thisError = $(this).parent().siblings('.error');
    if(thisClass[1] == "letters"){
        if(thisValue.length <= 1){
            thisTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                thisError.html("You must have at least 2 characters");  
                thisError.show();
            }, 800);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
            thisError.hide();
            thisError.html(""); 
        }
    }
});

$('input').keydown(function(){
        clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
        thisError.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great explanation and Bonus for answering the main question!  Accepted!

Answer (score 4):

You may be overwriting the previous setTimeout id. Thus you would not be able to clear it out.

```
var thisTimeout;
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    var thisValue = $(this).val();
    var thisError = $(this).parent().siblings('.error');

    if(thisClass[1] == "letters"){
        if(thisValue.length <= 1){
            clearTimeout(thisTimeout); // <-- already clear the timeout here before 
                                       // starting another one
            thisTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                thisError.html("You must have at least 2 characters");  
                thisError.show();
            }, 800);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
            thisError.hide();
            thisError.html(""); 
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would work to me because `thisTimeout` is a local variable that goes out of scope so when you later want to use it, its value is gone.

Comment: @jfriend00, good call. I promoted it. I was more concerned about the idea of clearing the previous timeout. And I wasn't thinking about the scope.

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you jfriend and Joe!  I thought I was making it global enough - but I didn't realize that everytime I had a keyup, the variable would reinstate again.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to move `thisTimeout` to a higher scope so its value is preserved and you have to clear it before you overwrite the previous value:

```
var thisTimeout;
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    var thisValue = $(this).val();
    var thisError = $(this).parent().siblings('.error');
    if(thisClass[1] == "letters"){
        if(thisValue.length <= 1){
            clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
            thisTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                thisError.html("You must have at least 2 characters");  
                thisError.show();
            }, 800);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
            thisError.hide();
            thisError.html(""); 
        }
    }

});
```

FYI, this code can be cleaned up a bit too:

```
var thisTimeout;
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var thisError = self.parent().siblings('.error');
    if (self.hasClass("letters")) {
        if(self.val().length <= 1){
            clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
            thisTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                thisError.html("You must have at least 2 characters");  
                thisError.show();
            }, 800);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(thisTimeout);
            thisError.hide();
            thisError.html(""); 
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Very well explained, I hadn't realized

Comment: @ntgCleaner - I offered a version with the code cleaned up a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much, if I could up-vote again, I would.  I appreciate your answer!  Liam gets the check mainly because he answered the first question as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The already set time out is being replaced.. and isn't clearing